# social login expects to lead to questions.html via django urlpatterns, instead leads to home page

Tags: python, html, django, url-pattern

## social login expects to lead to questions.html

I am currently learning urlpatterns with django.

I expect that when I click on login via google, I will be redirected to `questions.html` Instead it leads to the home page.

### debugging steps:

1. I have tried adjusting the hyperlink in the templates/index.html template to point to templates/questions.html

```html
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}?next=/questions.html">Login With Google</a>
```

2. I have adjusted the user/urls.py file in users app (manages social login) to point to questions.html

```py
#users/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home), # home page
    path("questions/", views.logintoquestions), # questions page
    [...]
```

3. I have ensured the view function `logintoquestions` is defined in users/views.py

```py
#users/views.py
[...]
def logintoquestions(request):
    return redirect("questions.html")
```

migrations are all up to date and the urlpatterns

4. I have tried changing views.home to views.logintoquestions in users/urls.py

```py
#users/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.logintoquestions), # home page
    path("questions/", views.logintoquestions), # questions page
    [...]
```

page now redirects to questions.html immediately which is not what I want - I want specifically it to be used when the user logs in via google.

5. Reverted step 4 so that "" is `views.home`

```py
#users/views.py
def home(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

this successfully renders the "" page as index.html, closer to what I want.

6. I have tried updating the subsequent function to

```py
#users/views.py
def home(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")

def logintoquestions(request):
    return render(request, "questions.html")
```

now the homescreen works, and oauth login works, and it leads to `/questions.html` but with this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in classroommatrix.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
index/ [name='index']
questions/ [name='questions']
<slug:slug>/ [name='post_detail']
like/<slug:slug> [name='post_like']
summernote/
accounts/
questions/
accounts/
logout
The current path, questions.html, didn’t match any of these.
```

7. inspecting further I can see that clicking on this navbar link does lead to desired `http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions.html`.html page with desired view.

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'questions' %}">Top Questions</a>
```

however, social auth leads to the same error message in step 6.

### further reading:

“Django URLS documentation.” Django, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/. Accessed 9 Dec. 2023.

Answer (score 0):

**as is suggested in the error message in step 6, questions.html is not a valid urlpattern. urlpatterns do not recognise file names such as .html.**

1. I have updated the template to use no `/questions/` instead of `/questions.html`.

   ```html
    <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}?next=/questions/">Login With Google</a>
   ```
2. I have added a name to the urlpattern in users/urls.py

```py
#users/urls.py
    path("questions/", views.logintoquestions, name='questions'), # added name='questions'
```

```py
#users/views.py
def logintoquestions(request):
    return redirect("questions.html")
```